# Should we use computeIfAbsent instead of getOrPut?

Tags: kotlin, concurrenthashmap

Kotlin has had an extension function `ConcurrentMap.getOrPut` from the beginning (1.0). This has the same signature as Java's `computeIfAbsent` and does a similar thing, but with some subtle differences:

1. `getOrPut` can put a null value into the entry, whereas `computeIfAbsent` doesn't support it.
2. `getOrPut` does not guarantee that the default function will only be called once, whereas Java's `computeIfAbsent` does guarantee that.
3. When `getOrPut` was released, the latest Java version was Java 8. In Java 8, `computeIfAbsent` always locked the entry even if the value was already there. Therefore, Kotlin may have had better performance because it doesn't lock when it doesn't need to.

However, in recent versions of Java (I've just checked 17) the locking overhead mentioned in point 3 is no longer there. So Kotlin's `getOrPut` no longer has that advantage, but it has the disadvantage of point 2. Under what circumstances should we continue to use `getOrPut` nowadays (assuming we don't want to put a null into a map) or should it now be considered "legacy"?

Comment: Does it matter? As you've already determined, they are more or less the same. If you care about calling `defaultValue()` twice, use `computeIfAbsent`. If you are purist and care about calling Kotlin API over Java API, do that. If you don't care either way, use whatever. And if the Kotlin developers consider it legacy, they will deprecate it. I don't expect that to happen, though (based on nothing).

Comment: Although it is guaranted neither by contract nor by documentation, the [current implementation of getOrPut does call default function at most once](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/46ea908daf0fec7dba309b358dc528c2e0c89ef7/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/MapsJVM.kt#L70). The doc says however that default function might be called even if a value already exists, because it is not "atomic". Then, default function could be called even if its value is not used. But it will be triggered only once.

Comment: @amanin no, the point is that defaultValue() could be called multiple times *by different threads*.

Comment: Then, your question comes down to: does atomicity matters in your context ? And without any more detail, only you can know that. Because atomicity starts to matter if either your default function triggers a side effect or cause performance penalty, and we can not deduce that from the information in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have pointed some very interesting facts for both methods.

Please consider an additional one which will be a reason to use `getOrPut`.

4. `ComputeIfAbsent` ensures atomicity. This means that this method can and will block other threads during computation to ensure atomicity.

From [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts
> to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it
> into this map unless null. **The entire method invocation is performed
> atomically**, so the function is applied at most once per key. Some
> attempted update operations on this map by **other threads may be
> blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be
> short and simple**, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of
> this map.

But `getOrPut` does not ensure atomicity.

From [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html)

> Note that the operation **is not guaranteed to be atomic** if the map is
> being modified concurrently.

This would mean that in a use case scenario, where atomicity is not important to you, `getOrPut` will offer performance benefits in comparison with `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: That's a good point. However, if I understand it correctly, the performance benefit of not having atomicity is not always present, and can sometimes be a penalty. Consider a default method that takes 100 milliseconds to calculate. Thread 1 starts first, and thread 2 starts 99 milliseconds later. If we use `computeIfAbsent`, thread 1 will lock, and thread 2 will be blocked for the last 1 millisecond, and then it will see the value that thread 1 had put in. On the other hand, if we use `getOrPut`, thread 2 will still spend a whole 100 milliseconds calculating a value that is then thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

One other difference is that `getOrPut` is inline, so it doesn't have to allocate the lambda function you pass to it. But in most cases, the more pressing requirement to consider is whether you need the change to be atomic.